# R odbc Impala Change from Default Database in Select

Tags: sql, r, odbc, impala

I have successfully connected to Impala using `R`'s `odbc` package. When I created the connection using my Microsoft ODBC Administator tool, I set the default database to `default`. This is a database which exists in this Impala instance, but it isn't one which I really care about. I just wanted to connect to the instance and bounce around between databases when I need to.

With SQL Servers connected via `odbc`, I can do this. Let's say I set up an `odbc` connection to a MS SQL Server and have the default database as `DB1`. If I wanted to query another database, say `DB2`, I could do this as follows:

```
library(odbc)
#set up connection to MS SQL server
mssqlcon <- dbConnect(odbc(), "ms_sql_server")

#query DB2
my_table <- dbGetQuery(mssqlcon , "SELECT * FROM [DB2].[dbo].[mytable])
```

I don't know how to do the equivalent of this using an Impala ODBC connection. Let's say there is a table called `imp_table1` on a database called `imp_db2` in the Impala instance I've connected to. The tricks I would use for MS SQL Server aren't working. Things I have tried are:

```
#impala connection
impcon <- dbConnect(odbc(), "Test Impala")
my_table <- dbGetQuery(impcon , "SELECT * FROM [imp_table1])
```

This throws an error saying `user does not have privileges to execute 'SELECT' on: default.imp_table1`

If I try the `USE` statement as described [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_create_database.html#create_database), I end up with a syntax error.

```
my_table <- dbGetQuery(impcon , "USE imp_db2; SELECT * FROM [imp_table1])
```

And finally, if I try to use syntax similar to what I use for SQL Server, I get the following error.

```
my_table <- dbGetQuery(impcon , "SELECT * FROM imp_db2.imp_table1) 

User  does not have privileges to execute 'SELECT' on: imp_db2.imp_table1
```

This error doesn't make sense because I can access this table using a web interface with my credentials and I can even use R Studio's Connection browser to preview columns in the data. I understand that it might be possible to change the connection setup in the MS ODBC Administrator so that I default to a different table, but I would prefer a single connection string that I can use to bounce around from database to database within the Impala instance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try `use imp_db2;` prior to your query?

Comment: @m_kinsey, Yes, that is one of the things I provided as an attempt in my example. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
my_table <- dbGetQuery(impcon , dbplyr::in_schema("imp_db2", "imp_table1"))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.